# Getting column value(database) from one table to another using hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

I've three tables in db:

- T1(id,name,age,start,end,mon,num)
- T2(num,name,sal)
- T3(num1,start,end,mon))

and three classes(A,B,C).

I want to map the data of T2(name) and T3(start,end) into the T1(name,start,end) table so that when querying for T1, I should see the data for id, name (coming from T2), age, start (coming from T3), end (coming from T3).

I tried by writing queries in the class A, but no progress.

```
List<A> data = JPA.em()
            .createQuery("select s.id like ? and c.name like ? and o.start like ? and o.end like ? from  A s, B c, C o where s.num=c.num " +
                    "and s.mon=o.mon ")
```

Comment: Should start and end be part of T2? What is the business reason to keep these attributes in different tables?

Comment: No. Because T2 and T3 tables also used by some other classes.

Comment: So what? what is the relationship between T1 and T3? For every row of T2 will there be exactly one row in T3?

Comment: I need to retrive "name" from T2(for T1) by using "num"(in both T1 and T2) and "start","end" from T3(for T1) by using the column "mon"(in both T1 nad T3)..